# how create a custom Auto-Configuration in parent maven project with quarkus

Tags: java, maven, metrics, quarkus, smallrye

**Request description:**
I want integration a few propertie (such as: quarkus.log.console.format、quarkus.smallrye-metrics.path) in
parent maven project, new project just extend parent maven project can be auto-config that propertie and make sure all project get same propertie.

**Simple relation:**
Auto-Configuration parent project (has propertie: quarkus.smallrye-metrics.path=/myMetrics)
｜———— A child Proejct (non-propertie)
｜———— B child Proejct (non-propertie)

use `http://${A project domain}/myMetrics` and  `http://${B project domain}/myMetrics` can get metrics.

**Tried:**

1. add `quarkus.smallrye-metrics.path=/myMetrics` in parent project/application.properties
2. read [source code](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/71189ce6ddc8a9d292d18fa57a0302dabcb0b192/extensions/smallrye-metrics/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/smallrye/metrics/deployment/SmallRyeMetricsProcessor.java#L99), but I can't find any way make it.

**env infomation:**

1. java version: 1.8
2. quarkus version: 1.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already supported in Quarkus since 1.13: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/15282

If you can't upgrade, you can use `microprofile-config.properties` instead which behaves the same way.

Comment: thanks you, I use `org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSourceProvider` make that.